# compiling with npm prod vs devq

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have a react code that while running in dev mode it updates a state and the interface gets updated. If this code is compiled for production the same state is updated but the interface is not re-rendered. I am using webpack to configure my dev and prod compilations. I understand this question might be very opened, but did any one had a similar experience and could tell me what he/she did to make things go well? i.e. that if code runs in dev mode then it also runs in production mode? I am tracking this situation and so far I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours I found the answer. I was running a code similar to:

```
setObj.forEach(function(point){
  if(point.x > 10){
     console.log(setObj.delete(point))
  }
})
```

this code will run pretty well in Development but if compiled to production eliminating console.log commands then   setObj.delete(point)   will never execute.
I just learned a serious lesson respect of console.log and compilation for production.